# Check for class in div added dynamically in v-for loop with .classList.contains only detects class of first item created

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs3

I want to detect a specific class (*.the-other-class-I-want-to-see*) on one of the elements created in the v-for loop. The classes get attached to the div dynamically coming from a .js file from store. Attaching the classes (*.one-of-the-classes-I-want-to-see* and *.the-other-class-I-want-to-see*) works perfectly fine I can see everything is created as expected, but when I use @mouseenter and fire up my function it always shows me the first entry only. I only want to change hover to !hover if *.the-other-class-I-want-to-see* is detected. Since *.one-of-the-classes-I-want-to-see* is the first entry in my store file it only detects this one, if I switch those two classes it will only detect the other one. I tried to store the class in an Object with a mounted() function but the result stays the same. Console.log shows me <div class="overall-class .one-of-the-classes-I-want-to-see" ... no matter which of the elements I'm hovering. Thanks everyone.

My v-for loop:

```
     <div
        v-for="(entry, index) in this.$store.state.file.area
        :key="index"
        id="specific-id"
        class="overall-class"
        :class="entry.theClassesIWantToSee"
        @mouseenter="myFunction()"
        @mouseleave="myFunction()"
      >
```

My method:

```
   methods: {
    myFunction() {
      const element = document.querySelector("#specific-id");
      console.log(document.querySelector("#specific-id"));
      if (element.classList.contains("the-other-class-I-want-to-see")) {
        this.hover = !this.hover;
        console.log("hover activated");
      } else {
        console.log("nothing to see here");
      }
    },
  },
```

Comment: Should you change `contains(".the-other-class-I-want-to-see")` to `contains("the-other-class-I-want-to-see")` --> drop the dot; it's a CSS class selector

Comment: tried it, doesn't change it. but I edited it in my initial question